# Swift: how to define a wildcard for a generic class

Tags: swift, generics

I've defined the following generic class:

```
class HView<V: UIView> {
    let vw: V
    init(_ vw: V) {
        self.vw = vw
    }

    var view: UIView { 
        get { return vw } 
    }
}
```

How would I define the following to hold instances of this class?

```
var hviews: [HView]   // Error: reference to generic type 'HView' requires arguments in <...>
var hviews: [HView<?>]   // Error: Expected Type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not java :P

you need define typy

```
var hviews: [HView<UILabel>]
```

You can also define protocol, and after implement this protocol

```
protocol HViewProtocol {
    var view: UIView { get } 
}

class HView<V: UIView>: HViewProtocol {
    let vw: V
    init(_ vw: V) {
        self.vw = vw
    }

    var view: UIView { 
        get { return vw } 
    }
}

var hviews: [HViewProtocol]
```